# embed infusionsoft form/iframe in a lightbox

Tags: jquery, lightbox, infusionsoft

I've got an infusionsoft signup form which I'd like to embed in a lightbox.

I've got the script for the form:
   `<script src="https://st990.infusionsoft.com/app/form/iframe/4342343243243" type="text/javascript"></script>`

and an example lightbox that works:

`<a rel="wwlba" href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3434343?hd=1&amp;width=870&amp;height=490&amp;fmt=22">
    <img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-1949 opaque" style="border: 0pt none; margin: 0px;" title="req" src="http://www.ccc.com/wp-content/uploads/video_screen.jpg" alt="" width="280" height="116" />
    </a>`

But when I try to do that with the infusionsoft iframe it doesn't render anything at all.

`` `<a rel="wwlb" href="https://st990.infusionsoft.com/app/form/iframe/4342343243243">
    <img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-1949 opaque" style="border: 0pt none; margin: 0px;" title="req" src="http://www.ccc.com/wp-content/uploads/video_screen.jpg" alt="" width="280" height="116" />
    </a> ``

Any thoughts?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the html version of the infusionsoft form.